# Where has performance monitor SQL logging gone in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, performance-monitoring

I'm quite used to having the option of logging windows performance counters to an MSSQL database since Windows 2000.

I've just tried setting up some performance counters on a new machine today and found the relevant options are no longer present in the properties dialog for a Data Collector Set.

Am I looking in the wrong place, or has this feature been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have been looking at an already defined data collector set?  It's only an option when setting up a new one.

I see it when I open PerfMon >> Data Collector Sets >> User Defined >> New Data Collector Set >> Data Collector Properties

There I can set log format as SQL and define a data source for logging.

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788038.aspx) describes doing it from shell if needed.

Comment: Ah-ha!
The log output is configured on the individual Performance Counter _within_ the data collector set - a concept I was not familiar with.

Thankyou William!